# Binding a collection for display in a gridviewcolumn using celltemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a collection of items where the last column is a collection with a celltemplate of it's own.
The ListView's item source is set dynamically in code and all of the other columns are rendering correctly. However, the final column's data is not being read at all. I've tried different solutions from other questions, but they don't seem to work for me.

```
    <Window x:Class="bbowl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="Blood Bowl Data" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SkillTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=description}" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Blue"><TextBlock.TextDecorations><TextDecoration /></TextBlock.TextDecorations></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SkillsTemplate">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" HeadersVisibility="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Skills}" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SkillTemplate}" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="cbxRace" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" Height="25" SelectionChanged="cbxRace_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        <Label Content="Rerolls:" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,25,0,0" Name="lblRerollLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="435" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Label Content="0" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,25,0,0" Name="lblReroll" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
        <ListView Height="263" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,48,0,0" Name="lvwPlayer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="MA" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ma}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ST" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=st}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="AG" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ag}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Max" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=max}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=price}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Skills" CellTemplate="{StaticResource SkillsTemplate}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What about setting your `DataGrid` in `<DataTemplate x:Key="SkillsTemplate">` `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`? It looks like that your `DataGrid` needs manually added columns if `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you would need to change your `SkillsTemplate` to something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SkillsTemplate">
   <DataGrid 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      HeadersVisibility="None" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Skills}" 
      BorderThickness="0" 
      GridLinesVisibility="None">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource SkillTemplate}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

which instead of changing whole items template creates one column that displays your text using `SkillTemplate`. However, as far I can see, for what you want to do with it you may consider using less complicated control like [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) or even [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) when you just want to display bunch of items without giving user option to select one

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SkillsTemplate">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Skills}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SkillTemplate}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```